# Successful login redirect to different page and signup different page using auth in laravel5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When user register after registration it will redirect to different page and after login it will redirect to some different page.I am using laravel5 auth.
How can i achieve this using laravel5 auth?

Comment: You can override either function in your `AuthController` so you can set your own redirectPath.

Comment: what have you done for this ? did you used any solutions suggested below ?

Comment: @motto I have used logic of your hint and integrate with my own different code.

Comment: well, if my answer is helpful please consider it to accept.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a simplier way without modifiying vendor files. You only need to use session or cookies for tracking if user logged in or just signed up.

in the login page:

> resources/views/auth/login.blade.php

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<?php $_SESSION["auth_type"] = "login"; ?>
```

in the sign up page:

> resources/views/auth/register.blade.php

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<?php $_SESSION["auth_type"] = "register"; ?>
```

in the user dashboard:

> app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php

```
/**
 * Show the application dashboard to the user.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    if($_SESSION['auth_type']=="register") {
        return redirect('user/registered');
    }

    if($_SESSION['auth_type']=="login") {
        return redirect('user/logged');
    }

    return view('home');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. As you are using Default Authentication of Laravel 5.

> It uses a PHP trait which contains all logic of login and register.

Check This file in your laravel project and change your redirect urls.

> \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php

Comment below if you have any issue.

Comment: In auth/authController.php already have  protected $redirectTo = "/dashboard"; but this will work for both login & signup. My doubt is how can i separate this redirect for login & signup. For example after login it will redirect to dashboard but after signup it will redirect to tour not on dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

If logged in, redirect to intended (intended means you tried to go to admin like pages but system redirected you to login page) location if it has, else to location specified inside intended().

```
if (Auth::validate($credentials))
{
    return Redirect::intended('route_to_redirect');
}
```

See /var/www/stock/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.php

```
/**
 * Create a new redirect response to the previously intended location.
 *
 * @param  string  $default
 * @param  int     $status
 * @param  array   $headers
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function intended($default = '/', $status = 302, $headers = array(), $secure = null)
{
    $path = $this->session->pull('url.intended', $default);

    return $this->to($path, $status, $headers, $secure);
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Bishal can you explain me this? I haven't understand this.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect path after registration is either of the ff as stated in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers`:

- `$redirectPath` if set
- else `$redirectTo` if set
- else `/home`

The redirect path after auth login is defined by `redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());`. The ff redirect path is used:

- session value `url.intended` if set
- else `$redirectPath` if set
- else `$redirectTo` if set
- else `/home`

To override the redirect path after login you can do either:

- Override the `postLogin()` function and redirect to your desired path
- In the `getLogin()` function, you can set the session `url.intended` value using the ff code:

  ```
  \Session::set('url', ['intended' => YOUR_DESIRED_ROUTE]);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

use $redirectPath=''; for path after register. and $redirectTo=''; for path after login.